# Concatenation of query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do i concatenate

```
SELECT abc, 
       abcd 
FROM   table 
WHERE  abc IN (SELECT efg 
               FROM   table2 
               WHERE  gfh LIKE'%a%')
```

in single quotes. I am having a problem while concatenating `',% and )` at the end of this query.

Comment: Any feedback to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the quoting string literal technique. The syntax is `q'[...]'`, where the "[" and "]" characters can be any of the following as long as they do not already appear in the string.

- !
- [ ]
- { }
- ( )
- < >

---

**Test case**

```
SQL> SELECT
  2  q'[select abc, abcd
  3     from table
  4    where abc in
  5       (select efg
  6           from table2
  7          where gfh like '%a%')]' str_concat
  8  FROM dual
  9  /

STR_CONCAT
-----------------------------------------------
select abc, abcd
   from table
  where abc in
     (select efg
         from table2
        where gfh like '%a%')


SQL>
```